# Make the 0 points for a self-accept clearer

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, accepted-answer, self-answer, reputation-history

When I first saw the new reputation tab report of a self-accept (without remembering I had accepted my own answer), I was quite puzzled by the action. I thought at first it was an accept/unaccept, but it didn't say +15 and -15. Could this be made a bit clearer? Perhaps either a note on each event saying it was a self-accepted answer, or perhaps just a single event for the accept?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hmm, I missed this request earlier - definitely could be better.

Starting with the next build the no-value row above will be removed (the (0) one will remain) and the tooltip will indicate it was your own answer.